# Use columns in a file as output file variable names

Tags: bash, awk, xargs

head testregions.bed

```
21      15390708       
21      15890068        16388793
21      16390041        16888505
21      16889055        17388185
21      17388731        17886839
```

I wanted to use each line of the .bed file as outputname
e.g:

```
while readline  
do zip.sh > 21_15390708_ 15889554.zip
            21_16390041-16888505.zip
```

I read a bit about xargs being able to do this. 
But I am stuck on how it can output each line to unique output file name.

```
xargs -a testregions.bed -I {} zip inputfile {} >> outputfile_{}.zip
```

and so on.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I  tried with below command  and achieved as below let me know for any
 modifications  awk '{print $1"_"$2"_"$3}' p.txt    output
:21_15390708_
21_15890068_16388793
21_16390041_16888505
21_16889055_17388185
21_17388731_17886839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy-to-understand way you can do this for every line in your `testregions.bed`. First, delete all the whitespace in your original file `testregions.bed` and save just the numbers into a new file `new.txt` like this:

`cat testregions.bed | tr -d "[:blank:]" > new.txt`

Then, you will create a new file for each line in your `new.txt` like this:

`cat new.txt | while read line
do
        touch "$line".zip
done`

And then you can delete the `new.txt`:

`rm new.txt`

So your script `test.sh` to create `.zip` files of `testregions.bed` would look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat testregions.bed | tr -d "[:blank"]" > new.txt
cat new.txt | while read line
do
        touch "$line".zip
done
rm new
```